# Is my yard not usable?

Tags: grading

We are in the process of buying a home - and the builder says the yard is "4:1" or a "25% grade" - I am trying to understand if this will need to be leveled, and at what cost to be able to use the yard for a swing set/etc - just an estimate?

The yard is 45 feet at the longest edge, 40 feet on the shortest edge. The width is about 56 feet. The slope is most from the back of the fence to about halfway into the yard, for "drainage".

Are we buying a HILL?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are buying a hill. You will have a hard time walking up a 25% grade, unless you build some steps. One side of that slope is 10 feet higher than the other side. If you can't go to look at it, or at least get a skype video link to somebody on the site to see what it's like, I wouldn't even think about buying it "sight unseen". I would be very concerned that the foundation of the HOUSE isn't going to be stable, close to a slope as steep as that.

Comment: This is what a 28% grade looks like: https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/624/cpsprodpb/16EB0/production/_95127839_hi009148226.jpg

Comment: My "backyard" for 7 years was a about a 20% grade. We couldn't even mow it well on a riding mower (could only go vertically up hill and not horizontally across the hill, which can lead to gullying). If your hill starts at about halfway between the yard and house, your backyard will effectively be about 20 feet long. And the big question is - WHERE DOES THE RUNOFF GO? Your yard should also slope away from your house at a grade steep enough to prevent a heavy rainfall from flooding the yard between the house and base of the hill and then into your house. If you can get out of this deal, do so.